# Parsing JSON with dynamic keys in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I am trying to parse JSON files from an url. This JSON has a key that is dynamic, in that it changes per file. Right now my code looks like this:

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)


                // Parsing
                if let stations = json["observations"]!!["-10019482"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

                    for observation in stations {

                        if let name = observation["stationname"] as? String {

                            if let temperatuuri = observation["Temperature"] as? String {
                                if let windSpeed = observation["WindSpeedMS"] as? String {
                                    print(name, temperatuuri, windSpeed,"m/s")
                                    self.temperature.text = String(temperatuuri)
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
```

"-10019482" is the part that changed dynamically and the key name cannot be predicted. However, I know that it is always the first key inside "observations".

How would I do the same, but without searching for a specific key name?

Comment: If you are sure that it is first key then use like json["observations"][0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `json["observations"]` is a dictionary you could do something like this to obtain it's first key

```
guard let dict = json["observations"] as? [String: AnyObject],
    let firstKey = dict.keys.first else { return }

print(firstKey) // should print the first key found in the observations dictionary
```

Comment: Hi again donnywals! I just updated my project to Swift 3, which broke this solution. Now it is complaining on the first line of the code you gave that 'Type 'Any' has no subscript members'. I tried solving this but couldn't find any way. Do you know a possible solution?

Comment: You should cast your JSON to a dictionary first: `let jsonDict = json as? [String: AnyObject]` and take it from there